# BindView and UnbindVIew in Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, rx-java, android-recyclerview

Is there any way to find out when a view is being used for some other position in an adapter. For e.g. there are 10 positions. and View has been created for first 4 of them. When we scroll up, the first view will now be reused for item 5. I need to know the moment that particular view is not being used for item 1. 
The use case is that, I am using observables inside the viewholder and need to unsubscribe at the right time.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods from [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) are handy in such case:

- [`onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH))
- [`onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH))

When the row is invisible but is about to be **visible** due to scrolling in, the first method is called.

When the row is visible and it becomes **completely** scrolled out of the screen the second method is called.

Both methods have [`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html) as parameter. If this is not enough you might obtain it's position by calling:

```
holder.getAdapterPosition()
```